# Updating the sqflite database if an item to the cart has already been added and creating if it is a new one in flutter

Tags: flutter, cart, sqflite

```
 dbHelper.insert(
Cart(
id:null,
productId:snapshot.data[index].name,
productImage:snapshot.data[index].image)
.then(...)
```

I have created a DBHelper and have succesfully added them to my cart list but now I want to create data for my cart if it's a new item and if the item already exists in my cart list then I want to update the fields in my database.
So how can I query (sqflite) so that I create rows for new items and update for the previous ones through the id(primary) or through(productId which is also unique).

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but i think you can do custom SQL request like this:

```
INSERT INTO cart (product_id, ...)
VALUES ('145', ...)
ON CONFLICT(product_id) DO UPDATE SET quantity = quantity + 1;
```

To execute a custom SQL request with sqflite:

```
await db.rawQuery('SELECT * from mytable WHERE id = ?', [objectId]);
```